# Using Aspose DLL Repeating the signature (Paragraph) in the document

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Using Aspose DLL i want to find the particular Paragraph and repeat that paragraph in the document below the old paragraph using One key word.

```
Here is the example
---------------------------------


Document Content..................
.................................
.................................
..................................

Dated This [Date of Report]
[Name of all existing directors] 
Director


here we need to create the documents for each directors here directors came dynamically       from data base. 

Document data is same for all the directors.
```

Comment: post any code you've attempted..

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not very clear. However, using IReplacingCallback, you can find the paragraph of the key string. Following is a simple code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Load in the document
    Document doc = new Document("C:\\data\\Testing.doc");

    //Regular expression for findinf Full Name string   
    Regex regex = new Regex("Full Name", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    //To find the text and insert the paragraph
    doc.Range.Replace(regex, new ReplaceEvaluatorFindandHighlight(), true);

    doc.Save("C:\\data\\document_new.doc");    

}

//Class to find the text as per key string
private class ReplaceEvaluatorFindandHighlight : IReplacingCallback
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called by the Aspose.Words find and replace engine for each match.
    /// This method highlights the match string, even if it spans multiple runs.
    /// </summary>
    ReplaceAction IReplacingCallback.Replacing(ReplacingArgs e)
    {
        // This is a Run node that contains either the beginning or the complete match.
        Node currentNode = e.MatchNode;

        //Use Document Builder to Navigate to the paragraph
        DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder((Document)e.MatchNode.Document);

        builder.MoveTo(currentNode.ParentNode);

        //Insert a Paragraph break
        builder.InsertParagraph();

        //Insert the Paragraph for the Text we have search
        builder.Writeln(currentNode.ParentNode.ToString(SaveFormat.Text)); // Inserts a string and a paragraph break into the document. 

        // Signal to the replace engine to do nothing because we have already done all what we wanted.
        return ReplaceAction.Skip;
    }   
}
```

Refer Aspose.Words documentation to get indepth detail of [Finding Text](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to+Find+and+Highlight+Text) or [Extracting Paragraphs](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Extract+Content+Between+Paragraphs) as per your requirement.